# How to enable specific extensions in Firefox private mode?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, private-browsing

I'm planning to use time tracking plugins for my time spent on the web and would like the private browsing sessions to be counted in.

In Chrome you can separately enable specific plugins in Incognito mode but I failed to find a similar capability in Firefox, am I missing an obvious solution here?

Answer (score -1):

To tack the time you spend in Firefox, you can make a use of the plugin "Simple Timer". You can download the plugin from the URL https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simple-timer/